# Bounded Linear Functionals - Vector Space Proof

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I have a question similar to the one in the link [Bounded linear functionals, normed vector space proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3457878/bounded-linear-functionals-normed-vector-space-proof/3457886#comment8992766_3457886), but with a different sign. I need to prove that the following:
For any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i f_i = 0 \implies \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_ib_i \leq 0$ if and only if there exists a vector $x\in\mathcal{X}$ such that $f_i(x) \geq b_i$ for all $i \in \{1,...,n\}$.
Would the proof be as simple as just changing the sign in the proof above? I don't think it can be, since we can't use the fact that $b$ is in the image of the linear functional now. I would appreciate your help :)